# How to setup benchmarkdotnet in abp boilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, benchmarkdotnet

I'am trying to setup benchmark to improve/optimise the code in the application, not benchmarking abp itself.
Example of benchmarking that i want to monitor: ef query refactoring or using dapper instead of ef core in some cases.

Thanks for your help